# Is it OK to fake a promise on a new angular resource?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with $resource in Angular 1.3.

I have a bunch of controllers with methods that work with the resource objects.

When the state of retrieval matters, these methods use the $promise property of the resource to ensure that they only process the objects after they are retrieved. These all work fine with existing and updated resource objects.

`var ProposalResource = $resource(proposalUrl, {id: '@id'}, {'update': {method: 'PUT'}});`

The resource objects are obtained by `ProposalResource.get({id:...`.

However, when I create a new resource object in order to make a new object using `new ProposalResource(...`, the methods fail because the $promise property is undefined.

I've worked around this by setting the $promise property on the new resource object to a resolved promise.

This seems to work OK but it feels like a nasty kludge. The option of explicitly checking for whether or not the $promise property is defined in all the other methods is even less appealing though.

Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: You should provide as with more details of what you are actually doing. `$resource` creates a resource "class" which can then be used to create resource instances. Those instances have a `$promise` property from the very start, so your problem wouldn't exist. Maybe you are wrapping `$resource` into something, that could explain `new ProposalResource()`.

Comment: I've clarified further. The $promise property is only present when you get an existing object, my problem is that I need to treat the new object consistently with existing objects - the new object may not need to be saved depending upon what the user does with it.

Comment: I understand. Then the approach using `q.when()` as proposed by @TomMcGeehon seems a reasonable solution. Another one would be to decorate `$resource` so that all resources have a `$promise` property. Which is kind of what you do, but only once ;)

Comment: Yes, decorating the $resource is effectively what I'm doing and I've been looking at Restangular et. al. for further help in this area. I don't see how $q.when helps me in this context - I've commented @TomMcGeehon's answer to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to use ProposalResource, but I usually use the $q provider.

That way you can do a simple function that returns a promise and you can call it from your controller methods.

Example service that uses a promise:

```
function someServiceMethod(params) {
    //do something here, maybe create an object,maybe make a call with $http or something
    var obj = createSomeObject(params);
    //this resolves the object once the createSomeObject method or function have completed
    $q.when(obj);
}
```

This approach is easier than doing the whole: `var deferred = $q.defer();` and return deferred.promise after the deferred.resolves.

If you're using $resource, then I recommend just using $http provider from angular.

Here's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
Here's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: I don't think when is appropriate in this context unless you are sometimes returning a promise from `createSomeObject` and sometimes not. The $resource is saving me a lot of $http repetition so I want to continue using it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to create a new $resource object. Can you give an example of how you are doing this?

Comment: I've further clarified my question. I'm using new because I'm making a new object which I sometimes later $save().

Comment: Paul, sorry for all of the confusion. I believe that your resource is not able to be instantiated. You'll have to fetch the resource that you'll want to use to update. Look the angular $resource page for "Creating a custom 'PUT' request", I think that is what you will need to do. I normally handle data sets and not single instances of a data type, so I typically use $http to return my data and modify/update/delete accordingly in the logic. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @Tom, instantiating the resource is correct for creating a new object. It can subsequently be $saved - this all works fine thanks to Angular. The problem was the methods that work with the resource and check if it is loaded. These methods are generally agnostic with respect to whether it is a new resource or not but were failing for new resources without the kludged $promise. They work fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the **[$resource AngularJS Doucmentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)**:

> Class actions return empty instance (with additional properties
>   below). **Instance actions return promise of the action.**

The statement above gives you a hint that **instance action** methods, **$get, $save, ...** and any other actions that you define in your `$resource` action definition, will always return a promise.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XMDW5EahOOHYCJh3b6I?p=info)**

e.g.

```
var User = $resource('user.json', {}, {
  'update': {'method': 'PUT'}
});

var user = new User();

// this sends a GET request to user.json and returns the promise directly
// from the instance action.
user.$get()
  .then(function(latestUserData) {
    // latestUserData is also an instance of the User resource
    return latestUserData.$update({
      'name': 'Ryan'
    });
  })
  .then(function(updatedUserData) {
    // do whatever you want here
  });
```

As you can see, the instance action `$get` returns a promise and when that promise is resolved, the `.then()` callback returns the response data from the server and at the same time it is wrapped/instantiated with the User `$resource`.

Comment: Thanks ryeballar, this is all well known to me. I don't see how it answers or addresses my question though.